# Salesforce to delta table

Tags: salesforce, azure-databricks, delta-lake

My source is Salesforce to get data incrementally and load in delta table databricks now how do I perform testing if both source and sink are matching .since the data is huge I'm unable to get count from source.any help appreciated

Comment: You need to break the data into little parts and compare each one individually.

Comment: Well the data is partitioned....the problem is we don't have access to Salesforce and to get count of source from ADF is very difficult using lookup activity ...  Can we generate some report to get that count